# Check authorized_keys to see which key was used for pushing the commit

Tags: git, bash, ssh, git-bash, authorized-keys

Say there's a large list of ssh public keys in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on a server with Git repositories, with a general format of " user@mail.com"

I want to write bash script for the pre-receive hook, that checks which SSH key was used to push the commit and then performs certain operations on the commit before it's received. So the outline of the script would be..

```
#!/bin/sh
#
<Check key which was used from authorized_keys for the commit>
<Print email corresponding to the SSH key to a file as a log>
<Do some other stuff here>
```

But since the server stores public keys, and private keys are used to push the commits, is it possible to check which key was used? If so how?

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, just need some direction to get started.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is, with some specific plumbing, exactly how gitolite does its work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm looking into gitolite, looks promising.
However, I still think there would be some way that I could use ssh with bash to compare keys from the commit to authorized-keys

Comment: @Ankit What do you mean by "which SSH key was used to do the commit"? The commit was made on the client side, and did not need any SSH key. Do you mean to say which SSK key was used to do the PUSH?

Comment: gitolite does this, it does it by controlling the command that was run, you might not need to do that exactly to get what you want but I don't believe (by default at least) that the running shell session knows anything about the ssh key that was used.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss Yes! Sorry for not being clear on that. The commit will occur on the client, and the push would require an SSH key that was in the authorized_keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE%20FORMAT) file to include an environment variable or custom command to run associated with each key.

Let's say you have the following public keys in your `authorized_keys` file:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA.... usera@hosta
ssh-rsa AAAA.... usera@hostb
ssh-rsa AAAA.... userb@hostc
```

And you want to be able to get the user's email associated with each of those. You could edit `authorized_keys` to instead read:

```
environment="EMAIL=usera@example.com" ssh-rsa AAAA.... usera@hosta
environment="EMAIL=usera@example.com" ssh-rsa AAAA.... usera@hostb
environment="EMAIL=userb@example.com" ssh-rsa AAAA.... userb@hostc
```

Now in your script, you could just access the `EMAIL` variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

sendmail "$EMAIL" <<EOF
To: $EMAIL
From: admin@example.com

This is a test message
EOF
```

Note that this mechanism should be used for convenience if you trust your users, not security if you want this not to be able to be subverted. If you want this to be secure so that the users couldn't tamper with it, you need to use the forced command feature, in which all access goes through a wrapper command that only allows running the specific Git commands. You could write your own wrapper for this, but if you're going to go down this route just using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) is probably the best solution. If you did want to implement this yourself, [gitolite has a page explaining how it works](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html).

Comment: Awesome! This might work. It's not for security, I'm looking to standardize the commit made by the users on to the git repos since we have had people commit with multiple email addresses using the same ssh key. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview)** is able to use the ssh key only because it uses the [ssh "forced command" feature](http://web.archive.org/web/20140214110102/http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) which allows you to register (in `~/.ssh/authorized-keys`) a script ([the forced command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33318205/6309)) which will run no matter which command you originally specified.

Without that, as mentioned in "[Can I find out which ssh key was used to access an account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15575/7490)", you would need to [parse the sshd logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112120/7490), or to modify the `~/.ssh/authorized-keys` in some ways (adding for instance [environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147319/7490)).